# Need clarification on clean architecture and repository pattern

Tags: typescript, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

I'm continuously reading materials on this topic for past 4 weeks, i've seen many implementations on github and, so far i understand the purpose but, i'm having some problems with implementation.

Let's start with usecase. If i'm correct than `usecase` holds business logic and perform action like validating or fetching some data through `repositories` and return some business object.

You define interface for `repository` in application business layer, and you implement it in `interface-adapters` layer.

The `repository` implementation lives in `interface-adapters` and need some sort of datasource that you inject from outside (Where does datasource live), should i implement interface for datasource in this layer?

The most confusing thing for me are `models` and DTO's. What are `models` exactly, what is the purpose and why i want to use a `model`, I am using mongoose as an ORM, so, i assume that your schema is a `model`?

Which means that, `model` is just some data that you fetch from outside(for eg: Api, DB etc) and then you map this data to entity, and if so then where should i do the mapping (In repository or usecase or datasource)?

I haven't touched controllers, presenters, or view-models yet, because i'm already so confused.

Comment: Models, DTO's and View-Models are all effectively the same thing - ways of representing structured data. Typically 'Models' refer to DataBase Models (schema), 'DTO's' are Data Transfer Objects which are used to pass data around between services or endpoints (A WebAPI returns a DTO to the caller) and View-Models are used in the front-end for binding to a View (MVVM pattern for instance). This is, of course, all subjective and different companies/blogs/documentation use their own definition for them but this should be a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

In a purely 'clean' architecture, every layer should use its own models. So your ORM schema models are not the same as your entities or DTOs (but they will map from one to another). The mapping from schema models to your entities should happen in the repositories as they return entities. And where you need DTOs, may be for presentation, you do that mapping on that layer.